# How to store/serve user-customizable HTML templates?

Tags: ruby, templates, mongodb, template-engine, tumblr

I want to offer a tumblr-like functionality where you can select a template, and optionally customize the HTML of your template in the browser and save it.

Current stack: Mongo, Sinatra (for REST API) for prototype. Will likely be moving to a compiled, statically-typed language later.

Wondering how best to accomplish this. Options I've considered:

1. Store the HTML in mongo, and duplicate it for all user accounts. So the HTML for the template you choose gets written into your account. Obvious cons of space inefficiency and need to update all users that use that template (if un-customized - you customize it it becomes your own and I won't ever touch it) if the template changes.
2. Store the templates in templates collection, and put custom templates either into this same collection or into the user collection with the owner of the template. User references a template id. This is quite clearly better than 1 I believe. Especially because I won't need to pull the template every time the user object is pulled.
3. Some third party library? Open to suggestions here.
4. File system.

I will need to package up these templates (insert js and stuff the user shouldn't be exposed to) and then serve them. Any advice on how best to approach this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will depend on how often you foresee people customizing the template versus just going with a standard.  How about a hybrid approach?

That is, have a field in the user document that is created lazily (on use) that either stores the custom template, or maybe a diff from one of the standards (not sure about the level of customization you are planning to allow).

Then you can have the template field you describe in 2 above, with a "special" setting for custom templates.  While you still have the concern about pulling a template each time, you do have the advantage of knowing that these are some of your more dedicated users - saving a trip to the DB might be advantageous, or you might not care.

If you don't care about 2 trips to the DB for every user, then you take approach 2, add the custom templates to the templates collection and simply reference the new ID for each user that customizes.

It's a balancing act - is the extra data overhead in terms of pulling the template each time worth saving a round trip to the DB or do you want efficiency in terms of the data you get each time at the cost of multiple queries to the DB - only you can answer that one based on how you design your app and how people use it.

For the linked approach you might want to take a look at [Database References](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References) and [Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) in the MongoDB docs.